# How do you find the roots for $-x^2+4x-8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, factoring

I am having trouble finding the roots for $-x^2+4x-8$. I tried factoring it regularly and tried the quadratic formula and neither of them worked. Could someone please help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Apparently the quadratic formula does in fact work. When I tried it, the square root number was negative and as a result it gave me an error so I don't know what to do from there. I have been told this question involves complex numbers which I am not familiar with. Can someone please show me how to find the roots of this question with the quadratic formula?

Edit 2: The original question is to solve inequalities for $-x^4+3x^3-2x^2-16x+16<0$. I have found 2 roots already which are 1 and -2.

Comment: How can the quadratic formula "not work"?  Please describe the calculation you did.

Comment: Not so sure what's the problem. The quadratic formula must work. To make it a bit easier find the roots of $x^2-4x+8$ instead. (which are the same roots)

Comment: Can you show your attempt? The roots are complex numbers. Have you studied complex numbers?

Comment: Maybe you are confused by the fact that there are no real roots. Well, do you know what are complex numbers?

Comment: @Mark No I am not familiar with complex numbers. Could you explain it to me or maybe recommend a website or video?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No I have not studied complex numbers. Could you help me out with it?

Comment: Complex numbers allow us to write a number whose square is a negative number. If you have not studied complex numbers, then you have been studying math all this time in which this polynomial _has no roots._ Why are you looking for roots of this polynomial? What is the question you really need to answer?

Comment: Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Comment: The equation can be written as $(x-2)^{2}+4=0$. But $(x-2)^{2}+4>0$ for any real number $0$. So if you are not allowed to use complex numbers the answer is: there are no roots for this equation.

Comment: @DavidK I am taking an online course and I guess it assumes that you already know complex numbers. They did not even explain it or go over it or anything, they just assume you know it so I think I do need to go further into this question. I am suppose to solve the inequalities so I am in the stage of finding the roots. The original question is $–x^4+3x^3-2x^2-16x+16<0$ Can you do solve inequality questions with complex numbers?

Comment: You would have a better-presented question if you edit that information into the question and also show the work you have done. I have written an answer based on what I now know about what you were doing, but if it does not answer your question, someone might be able to do better if they knew a little more about what you need.

Comment: @DavidK Okay, good to know. Thank you for all of your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as per the comments of others, it lacks context.  Please edit your question to include some additional background (for example, the fact that you are unfamiliar with complex numbers might be relevant; it might also be helpful to know what your level of mathematical knowledge is---are you in high school, for example?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the information that the underlying problem you are trying to solve is to find out when $–x^4+3x^3-2x^2-16x+16<0.$

This question does not really even make sense if $x$ could be a complex number, so it is reasonable to assume that the course where you got this question did not want you to use complex numbers. So let's use only the kinds of numbers you know about,
which I suppose is the real numbers. (Even if you have not seen them called by that name, I will use it here, since it is much more convenient and precise to write
"real numbers" rather than "the kind of numbers  you have studied.")

I assume you have discovered that $-x^2+4x-8$ is a factor of $–x^4+3x^3-2x^2-16x+16.$

Now the fact that the quadratic equation asks you for the square root of a negative number is significant. It tells you that there cannot be any real number that is a root of $-x^2+4x-8$.
In order for the quadratic equation to produce a real number, the square root would also have to be real (technically this is only because all the parts outside the square root are real, but they are).
Now you may know that any real number, squared, produces a positive number
(except zero, whose square is zero).
And that is why you cannot find the square root of a negative number
when you must look for the square root among the real numbers.

In fact, you can write
$$-x^2+4x-8 = -(x^2 - 4x + 8) = -((x - 2)^2 + 4),$$
and now we see that for any real number $x,$ the quantity $x-2$ is also a number whose square is positive (or zero).
When we add $4$ to that we always get a positive number.
Then put the negative sign in front, and we always get a negative number.
So $-x^2+4x-8$ is always negative.

You should have found two other factors of $–x^4+3x^3-2x^2-16x+16,$
so you have three factors altogether.
In order for the product of all three factors to be negative,
given that $-x^2+4x-8$ is always negative,
you need to look for values of $x$ that either make both the other factors positive
($P\times P\times N \mapsto N$)
or make both the other factors negative
($N\times N\times N \mapsto N$).

Comment: I've only found two factors which are 1 and -2. What is the third factor you are referring to?

Comment: $1$ and $-2$ are _roots,_ which means that the polynomial has factors $(x-1)$ and $(x+2).$ The third factor is $(-x^2+4x-8)$. If you multiply all three together using multiplication of polynomials you should get $–x^4+3x^3-2x^2-16x+16.$

Answer (score 1):

An equation $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ with $A,B,C\in \Bbb R$ may or may not have any solution $x\in \Bbb R.$

For example $A=1,B=0,C=1:$ No $x\in \Bbb R$ satisfies $x^2+1=0.$

The Quadratic Formula says that if $A\ne 0$ then $$Ax^2+Bx+C=0\iff \left(x+\frac {B}{2A}\right)^2=\frac {B^2-4AC}{4A^2}.$$ So if $A, B,C\in \Bbb R$ with $A\ne 0$ and $B^2-4AC<0$ then there is no $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $Ax^2+Bx+C=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Let's apply the quadratic formula step by step to see where you went wrong.

Recall that for $ax^2+bx+c=0$, $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

In your case, $-x^2+4x-8=0$.

$x=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{(4^2)-((4)(-1)(-8))}}{2(-1)}$

$x=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{16-32}}{-2}=2\pm\frac{\sqrt{-16}}{-2}=2\pm\frac{{4i}}{-2}=2\pm-2i$

Thus, our roots are not real and are $x=2+2i$ and $x=2-2i$.